# Can "full of sweet wine" (Acts 2:13) be viewed as an assessment by not -understanding "others" of the message or its sound of "speaking in tongues?

Tags: acts, word-choice

Text: Acts 2:13 (YTL)

"And others mocking said, They are full of sweet wine."

Answer (score 1):

Acts 2:13 (BLB) says:

> But others mocking were saying, "They are full of new wine [γλεῦκος]."

The operative noun here, γλεῦκος, occurs only in this one instance in the NT.  According to BDAG, it simply means

> "sweet/new wine" ... commonly referred to as must.

This "must" is an abbreviation of the Latin "mustum" which is short for "vimum mustum" = fresh wine [often unfermented].  However, as Ellicott correctly observes:

> Here, [Acts 2:13] however, the context shows that wine, in the strict
> sense of the word, was intended, and the use of the same word in the
> LXX. of Job 32:19 confirms this meaning [ie, fermented and capable of
> inducing intoxication].

From the record in Acts 2, two facts become clear:

1. the behavior of the apostles who were speaking in "tongues" appeared to some, to be an exhibition of drunk and disorderly behavior
2. The disciples were not drunk but spoke a large series of foreign languages, intelligible to those listening, even in their local native dialects (V8, 11)

Thus, whatever the disciples were doing and saying, it was NOT a series of ecstatic utterances, known in modern times as "glossalalia" (which is not a Biblical word.)

One can confirm this by the deliberate contrast between the record in V11,12 vs. V13:

> **11** ... we hear them declaring the wonders of God in our own tongues!” **12** Astounded and perplexed, they asked one another,
> “What does this mean?”
>
> **13** But others mocked them and said, “They are drunk on new wine!”

Just why some heard what sounded like babbling and others heard "the wonders of God in our own tongues" can be easily understood by a simple fact:

If a member of the crowd, who only spoke (say) Aramaic, happened to be near a disciple explaining "the wonders of God" to a group of (say) Parthians, the speaker would sound drunk!  Recall that more than 16 language and ethnic groups were present at Pentecost (V9, 10).

Therefore, the amazement at the multitude of languages being spoken that day may well have produced expressions of madness until people worked out what was going on.

Comment: The word "glossolalia" is from "γλωσσολαλιά." It's a theological construct derived from γλῶσσα (glossa, meaning "language") and λαλεῖν (lalein, "to speak").

Comment: @Jess - that is true, but it does not appear in the NT

Answer (score 1):

The non-Christian people who heard the Christians speaking that day in their native languages (as spoken by them in Parthia, Media, Elam, Mesopotamia, Cappadocia, Pontus and Asia) voiced one particular question. They asked in amazement what was meant by this astonishing event. They had never heard Galileans speaking this myriad of foreign languages, in public, so that all the native speakers understood what the Galileans were saying.

It is important to register that point (as written in verse 12) before noting the sarcastic answer some of their fellows voiced. Some of those people from further lands mocked the Christians. Even though it was far too early in the morning for them to be full of sweet wine, they accused the Christians of being drunk. Ah, but Peter heard that accusation, stood up and publicly addressed it, showing he understood what was going on, and that it was the miraculous operation of the Holy Spirit that accounted for their ability to speak in many foreign languages.

The mockers were not full of sweet wine themselves, but neither were any of the Christians. The mockers could not account for this amazing miracle other than by thoughtlessly dismissing it as a load of people drunk, early in the morning. They had never heard the likes of it before, but instead of stopping to think and find out, they did what many foolish people do - shoot a mocking accusation from the hip.

***What they did understand perfectly well was that they heard these Galileans speaking in their own native languages.*** The account in Acts makes that clear:

> "And there were dwelling in Jerusalem Jews, devout men from every
> nation of those under the heaven, and the rumour of this having come,
> the multitude came together, and was confounded, because they were
> each one hearing them speaking in his proper dialect, and they were
> all amazed, and did wonder, saying one unto another, 'Lo, are not all
> these who are speaking Galileans? How do we hear, each in our proper
> dialect, in which we were born?' Acts 2:5-8 YLT

Note, however, that at first it was devout Jews who initially heard this speaking in tongues. But the mockers may well have been a later group that then quickly gathered, having heard a rumour. To repeat this possibility in verse 6:

> "And the rumour of this having come, the multitude came together, and
> was confounded, because they were each one hearing them speaking in
> his proper dialect." Acts 2:6 YLT

The initial group of devout Jews seem to be distinct from the somewhat later group of mockers. Given that some 3,000 men were converted to Christ that day, due to this miracle (verse 41), a huge number did not mock.

***The answer to the question indicates that only the mockers missed the point, perhaps because they were so taken up with the way the gospel message was miraculously delivered, rather than with the gospel message itself.*** They swiftly mocked and dismissed it all. But the devout people were stopped in their tracks by the power of the Holy Spirit in all of this. Three thousand were enabled to understand the gospel message.

Sadly, people living after that event show the same ways of responding to the gospel message: either being moved by the Holy Spirit to heed the message (as opposed to the manner in which it is delivered), or to mock and attribute natural causes to a divine operation of the Holy Spirit. In this day and age we see plenty evidence of religious **people being so taken up with apparent linguistic phenomena, they miss the gospel message that should have filled their ears** - and hearts. And when what is spoken turns out not to be the gospel of salvation, but messages about messages supposedly given to the messengers, then it should be clear that it's the wrong message. Those who understand when supposedly 'gospel' messages are not gospel at all, are not misunderstanding anything. But **those so taken up with signs and miracles that they deviate from the purity of the gospel are certainly misunderstanding**, as did those mockers back then.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here. Γλεύκους is the word used for wine in this passage. It is reference to wine that is very young, most likely less than a year old. It may or may not be sweet wine. The reference is that of people have a drinking party.

The first possibility is that the mockers are suggesting that the intoxicated disciples are spouting off, in the midst of intoxicating fun, the various languages that they have previously learned while functioning & living in a multi-ethnic culture. However, this would be rather ironic in light of how in Acts 4:13 the mockers looked at "Peter and John, and perceived that they were unlearned and ignorant men."

The second possibility it that this is an allegation of the disciples engaging in esoteric speech that is imitative of Dionysian worship practices. This would indeed be an example of how scoffers would have viewed the glossolalia phenomena on the day of Pentecost. For a cessationist view of this possibility occurring in Corinth, see Wayne House's
[Tongues and the Mystery Religions of Corinth.](http://www.seeking4truth.com/tongues_corinth.html)

For a modern skeptical form critical examination of Luke's Gospel and Acts as imitating Dionysian themes, see Katherine Dyer's work [here.](https://%E2%80%9CHEALING%20STEPS%E2%80%9D:%20JESUS%E2%80%99%20DIONYSIAC%20TOUR%20IN%20LUKE%20By%20Katherine%20Veach%20Dyer) Katherine concludes:

> ...while other myths of the god were certainly available at the time
> of Luke’s composition, the Gospel’s version of Dionysiac traits
> corresponds exactly to those found in Euripides’ Bacchae. Based on the
> use of the Bacchae in Acts, the evidence for its employment in Luke
> establishes the Euripidean tragedy as a valid source for the
> composition of the Gospel.

Traditional Christians would make a distinction between source and occasion for the imitation & contrasting of Dionysian themes in the life of Jesus and his disciples - as portrayed in Acts & Luke. The occasion was the desire to be culturally current with mythical based mystery religions of that time period. The source of the writings of Luke & Acts was that of the eyewitness testimony of Jesus, or close associates of the eyewitness of Jesus, and the events of his close disciples.

Traditional, non cessationist, Christians would appeal to the modern gift of tongues as serving as a type of reciprocal historical analogy for interpreting the gift of tongues in Acts and in Corinth. At times "in, with and under" the esoteric speech of glossolalia known identifiable human languages can surface from the spiritual "coded soul language" of the collective unconscious expressed in glossolalia. For example, see Larry Christenson's [Perplexed by Tongues.](http://www.lutheranrenewal.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Perplexed_by_Tongues.pdf)